# Return to a previous commit disregarding all changes

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using SourceTree and I would like to return to a previous commit while disregarding all changes. At this current stage, I cannot delete the changes as they were significant and SourceTree does not allow me to (I have updated a Nuget package and do not know the previous version).

Can you please help? Please see the current situation I am at on the attached picture.[image: Please see the arrow for the place where I would like to be]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stash the changes made with atlassian sourcetree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23898093/stash-the-changes-made-with-atlassian-sourcetree)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit

Comment: `git reset --hard <SHA of origin/develop>`? And yes, Sourcetree will let you do that; just right-click that line with the red error and choose Reset develop to...